# Set first options selected using jquery

Tags: jquery

There are two options lists with different names, i need to set first options selected in both of them.

```
<input type="radio" name="first_list" value="0">abc
<input type="radio" name="first_list" value="1">cba

<input type="radio" name="second_list" value="0">opc
<input type="radio" name="second_list" value="1">cpo
```

Sure, i can do this way:

```
$("input:radio[name='first_list'][value='0']").attr("checked", "checked");
$("input:radio[name='second_list'][value='0']").attr("checked", "checked");
```

Maybe there is another more compact way to do this?

Comment: Give them unique ids? I mean, how much more compact than 6 total lines of code can you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input:radio[value='0']").attr("checked", "checked");​
```

This worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jcolicchio/46WXn/

Comment: nice try! but what if i have more options lists which should not be changed?

Comment: `$("input.allow:radio[value='0']").attr("checked", "checked");​` I've added a class called "allow" to each input in the sets I want changed, then I select only inputs of class "allow", and apply it to those, as seen here:http://jsfiddle.net/jcolicchio/46WXn/2/

Answer (score 0):

If the markup you show above is complete you can use `prop` to check the boxes -

```
$('input:radio:even').prop('checked', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r82RE/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work no matter how many inputs you have on each set and even if the values are not consistent between sets:

`$( $( 'input[type=radio]' ).toArray().reverse() ).prop( 'checked', true );​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

It will actually check all radio inputs from last to first, but only the very first will remain checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:radio[value="0"]').prop("checked",true)

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="radio" name="first_list" value="0">abc
<input type="radio" name="first_list" value="1">cba

<input type="radio" name="second_list" value="0">opc
<input type="radio" name="second_list" value="1">cpo</body>
</html>
```